# how to increase size of all icons instead of individually for GUI console Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, image-scaling

Hi I am trying to increase the size of all icons in the GUI window instead of individually, I know the icons may get a little blurred but that is fine.

Currently all the icons are saved in a icon folder, So is it possible to increase the size of all the icons in one go instead of one by one.

This the code which increases the size of icons individually.

```
Resources.getIcon(iconName).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
```

Comment: iterate over all the icons, and in the iteration call that setPreferredSize

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for this is to scale your `Image` right after loading, and before you create the ImageIcon with it